# What is the procedure if both pilots are incapacitated?

Tags: emergency-procedures, pilot-incapacitation

Let's say both pilots passed out , is there anyone else from cabin crew that is trained enough to land a plane?

Comment: I wonder the possibility that this happened to MH370.

Comment: While there is no recorded incident of this ever happening for large airliners, there is the possibility of what is often known as "talk down aircraft landing" where someone is instructed over radio, however this is not part of any official procedures. There is the possibility to do training courses in some simulator facilities for exactly those things, though I have never heard of any airline doing this officially for their crew.

Comment: See [Helios Flight 522](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helios_Airways_Flight_522) for an example of this happening on an airliner. Unfortunately it was not a good outcome.

Comment: @Dezza wow , thanks for the example

Comment: Related: [Can a passenger realistically replace suddenly incapacitated pilots?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8986/755)

Comment: Also related: [How do commercial airlines prepare for pilots falling sick during the flight?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12986/755)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To put it short: no.

Unfortunately it might even take a while for anyone to notice both pilots are out. Most likely the first would be an air traffic controller since he/she couldn't reach the pilots on radio.
If the cabin attendants find both pilots incapacitated, they would most likely

- try to find a doctor or nurse to help recover a pilot
- try to find if any of the passengers was a pilot

Comment: It seems to me that a bigger problem might be access to the cockpit. Can the cabin crew open the cockpit door without the cooperation of the flight crew?

Comment: @dlu sorry, can't comment on that.

Comment: as in "don't know" or as in "you could tell us, but then you'd have to kill us." :-)

Comment: @dlu more the latter, not so strongly though :D

Comment: Whew, glad to hear that :-)